# Select2 widget send param.term spaces to ajax as "+" and not %20

Tags: javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2, encodeuricomponent

I'm working on an app that connects to SAP's service layer and make queries from the url (API REST). I'm using the famouse widget select2 but I'm having a problem. I need to make a query to the api, and its sentence has a space character (" "):

```
"(startswith(CardCode,'"+params.term+"') or startswith(CardName,'"+params.term+"'))
```

The spaces are those around the "or" operator.

So This is mi code:

```
$('#buscarCliente').select2({
        placeholder: "Ingrese código o descripción del cliente",
        allowClear: true,
        language: "es",

        ajax: {
            url: SLServer+"BusinessPartners",
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            delay: 550,
            params: {
                contentType: 'application/raw; charset=utf-8'
            },
            data: function (params) {
              return {

                $filter: "(startswith(CardCode,'"+params.term+"') or startswith(CardName,'"+params.term+"'))", // Como se va hacer la busqueda
                $orderby : "cardName",
                //contentType: 'multipart/form-data;boundary=<Boundary>',

                //$filter: "((startswith(CardName,'" + params.term.toUpperCase() + "') or startswith(CardCode,'" + params.term.toUpperCase() + "') or startswith(CardName,'" + params.term + "') or startswith(CardCode,'" + params.term + "')) and CardType eq 'C')&$top=15&$expand=PaymentTermsType",
                //$filter: "startswith(CardName,'" + params.term.toUpperCase() + "') or startswith(CardCode,'" + params.term.toUpperCase() + "')",
                page: params.page
              };
            },

            processResults: function (data, params) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
            // scrolling can be used
            params.page = params.page || 1;



            return {
              results: $.map(data.value, function(item) {
                    return { id: item.CardCode, text: "<b>"+item.CardCode+"</b> "+item.CardName }; //adecuamos el arreglo al select
                }),
              pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
              }
            };
          },
          cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        /*formatNoMatches: function (term) {
            return 'No se encontraron clientes con el código: "' + term + '".<br/><!--span class="link">Click&nbsp;here</span-->',
        },*/
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        //templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        //templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
      });
```

As you can see, I'm sending the query as a parameter joining the term that is being typed in the widget. The problema is that select2 is encoding the query such way that replaces spaces with a plus symbol (+) and not "%20" so the api rest service says it is an illegal character and I can't get my result.

This is the way it looks:

```
https://service.net:50000/b1s/v1/BusinessPartners?%24filter=(startswith(CardCode%2C%27CLIEN%27)+or+startswith(CardName%2C%27CLIEN%27))&%24orderby=cardName
```

As you all can see, the spaces around "or" operator are being replaced by plus symbols. I have tested the javascript function "encodeUri()" and "encodeURIComponent()" and it does nothing because i think it is being serialized in the code. I added the contentType, I replaced the spaces manually by "%20" but the result is being encoded and its worse (%2520)...

Can anyone help me. Is there a way to change this type of encoding so the spaces change to "%20" and not the damn "+"??

Thank you all!

Comment: As I'm sending a GET request, I know i can add the query to the url parameter, but I remember I need to get the term that is being typed in the search box, and I don't mind how to get it in that level...

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

I was reading about the documentation and found and important clue: I can get the ajax "url" property from a javascript function getting as a parameter the term being searched. So I built the url joining the query string and used the encodeURI javascript function and it worked! :-D

```
ajax: {
            ....

            url: function (params) {
                return SLServer+"BusinessPartners"+encodeURI("?$top=15&$filter=((startswith(CardName,'" + params.term.toUpperCase() + "') or startswith(CardCode,'" + params.term.toUpperCase() + "') or startswith(CardName,'" + params.term + "') or startswith(CardCode,'" + params.term + "')) and CardType eq 'C')&$expand=PaymentTermsType";);
            },

            ....
```

So the blank spaces are being translated in this function as %20 and the api is happy and spitting the results...

Hope this helps somebody else. Hugs from Venezuela ;-)